# Powershell code to automate removal of drive letter

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

Can someone help me out with a way on how to remove a drive letter from the drive with the least memory using powershell ? 
 I have a partition that is 7 mb and i want to remove the drive letter from it....

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Get the smallest volume:

```
# 'Fixed' type avoids choosing a CD-ROM drive with no media in it, at 0 bytes

$Volumes = Get-Volume | Where-Object DriveType -eq 'Fixed' 
$SmallestVolume = $Volumes | Sort-Object -Property Size | select -First 1
```

Then dig through the Scripting Guy blog to find out how to remove a drive letter, find the suggested method doesn't work, then use the comments to find a method which does work:

```
$SmallestVolume | Get-Partition | ForEach { 
    Remove-PartitionAccessPath -DiskNumber $_.DiskNumber -PartitionNumber $_.PartitionNumber -AccessPath "$($_.DriveLetter):"
}
```

I tried it once, YMMV. Needs to be 'run as' administrator, or `Get-Partition` will have no results.

- Bits taken from https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/07/powertip-use-powershell-to-remove-drive-letter/